# TextField overlapse another TextField - Android

Tags: android, layout, textfield, overlap

I've got a textfield that contain a film genres and another one that contain film description. The description is setted below the film thumb that have a fixed size and the genres are on the right of the thumb. Problem is that the genres can be to long to fit in the space i reserver and overlapse the description. I need to put the description below thumbs AND genres or maybe another way to prevent overlapsing.

film_information.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="149dp"
    android:id="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/titolo"
    tools:text="Main Title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/release_date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titolo"
    tools:text="Data rilascio"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/author"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/release_date"
    tools:text="autore"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/voto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/author"
    tools:text="Voto"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/durata"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/voto"
    tools:text="Durata"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/generi"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/durata"
    tools:text="Genere"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titDesc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumb_detail"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    tools:text="Descrizione"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />



     <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/descr"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titDesc"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried to use `LinearLayout` horizontal and inside it one `ImageView` and next to another `LinearLayout` vertical with `TextView`s? (not so flat way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `Layout` with below `Layout` it may be help to you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_detail"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Main Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/release_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        tools:text="Data rilascio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/release_date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        tools:text="autore" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/author"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        tools:text="Voto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/voto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        tools:text="Durata" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/generi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/durata"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_detail"
        tools:text="Genere" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    tools:text="Descrizione" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titDesc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah it's worked :) (7min and ill accept your answer )